# How to set 'UpdateCauses ' user permission on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use the build failure analyzer plugin for Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer

In the documentation it says

> The link is shown only if the permission UpdateCauses is set for the current user.

But it doesn't give any information on how what that is or how to set it.

I'm the only user for my Jenkins.

Thanks!

Comment: can you check if you have all permissions in your jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security` and under the `Access Control` section on `Authorization` there will be the users and their permissions (if you use matrix base security) you will see the Build Failure Analyzer permissions:

[image: Permissions Matrix]

So short answer, you configure the plugin permissions using Jenkins configurations.